# unable to load GL_RGBA16F in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

my system specs are i7 3rd generation amd hd7700 mobile graphics intel hd 4400 graphics

I wanted to know if there is a problem with my graphic card.
and I want to know how do I enable openGl to use my amd graphic card instead of HD graphics

I am getting a blank screen we I use this method

I wanted to know if the problem is in the code or m implementation is wrong

my Frame buffer:

```
unsigned int hdrFBO;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &hdrFBO);
// create floating point color buffer
unsigned int colorBuffer;
glGenTextures(1, &colorBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
// create depth buffer (renderbuffer)
unsigned int rboDepth;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
// attach buffers
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, hdrFBO);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "Framebuffer not complete!" << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

my Code in the Loop:

```
    glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();

    shader.Use();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, hdrFBO);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLint texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "diffuseTexture");
    glUniform1i(texLoc, 0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, diffuseMap);



    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "model");
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "view");
    GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "projection");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    GLint viewPosLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "viewPos");

    glUniform3f(viewPosLoc, camera.GetPosition().x, camera.GetPosition().y, camera.GetPosition().z);

    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4();
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0));
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(2.5f, 2.5f, 27.5f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

    renderCube();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);







    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    hdrShader.Use();

    GLint texLoc1 = glGetUniformLocation(hdrShader.Program, "hdrBuffer");
    glUniform1i(texLoc1, 0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);

    renderQuad();
```

[My fragment Shaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmzcK.png)

Comment: To select which of AMD/Intel driver is in use for your app, do it through "Graphics properties" or similar at OS level. From inside the app you can only ask for the name (glGetString) of the current one; but not select the desired one.

Comment: For you "blank screen" issue: use `glActivetexture` before filling the texture with data..